# Is it meaningful to create more than one object in Java?

Tags: java, class, oop, object

I think creating one instance of a class in Java is enough to fulfill all your requirements. Then why does Java allow for the creation of more than one object?

Comment: How you can say that single object can fulfill all requirements?

Comment: Just an example: Imagine you have a class `University`. This class `University` will contain a List of `Student`. As there is more than one Student, you will surely have to create more than one `Student` to fulfill the requirement, right?

Comment: `one instance is enough to fulfill all your requirement` - very interesting conclusion. I wonder what it's based on...

Comment: Ohh yes!  @maloomeister now I got the concept behind creating multiple objects. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An instance of a class is used to store states. The states can vary across different instances of the same class.

For example -

```
Class Student {
int rollNumber;
String name;
int age;
}
```

When you have 50 students in a class, you need to create 50 instances of the Student class. Each instance will relate to one real-word student. Every instance will have its own name, roll number and age.
That's why you need multiple instances of the same class.

Comment: Absolutely correct, now I got it. Than you @Dhumil

Answer (score 0):

In Simple programs, which are mostly are demonstrations or practice examples, an Object per class works. However, when you imagine real life complex programs, where high volume records of n number of accounts being processed, then you realize the power of parallel processing.